# How to detect blank line using streamtokenizer in java

Tags: java

hi guys I'm parsing a text file using a stream tokenizer that contains

Z

Z (ze; in England commonly, and in America sometimes, zêd; formerly,
also, îz"zêrd)

Defn: Z, the twenty-sixth and last letter of the English alphabet, is
a vocal consonant. It is taken from the Latin letter Z, which came
from the Greek alphabet, this having it from a Semitic source. The
ultimate origin is probably Egyptian. Etymologically, it is most
closely related to s, y, and j; as in glass, glaze; E. yoke, Gr.
yugum; E. zealous, jealous. See Guide to Pronunciation, §§ 273, 274.

my code

```
 public int[] getlineno(){
 try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(url));
            StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(in);
            st.eolIsSignificant(true);
            Vector v=new Vector();
            st.commentChar('#');
            scan:
            while (true) {
                switch (st.nextToken()) {
                    case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
                        break scan;

                    case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
                        break;

                    case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
                        break;

                    default:
                        if(st.sval==null){
                        System.out.println(i+" "+st.sval);
                        v.add(st.lineno());
                        }break;

                }
            }
            int linesno[]=new int[v.size()];
            for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
                int line=Integer.parseInt(v.get(i).toString());
                linesno[i]=line;
            }
            return linesno;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
```

}

Please, help me to detect the blank line using the streamtokenizer.class

Comment: Please help us and yourself with the code you have tried ?

Comment: I've indented your text to make it more readable. Are the bold `**` markups necesssary?

Comment: blank line can just be a new line char, end of line char followed by a new line char, or just a line full of spaces. I hope you can handle this now.

Answer (score 1):

There's a form of StringTokenizer constructor that takes the string, a list of delimiters and a boolean that indicates whether the delimiters should be returned as tokens in their own right.  If you use this form of the constructor, the nextToken() method will return the new line character (assuming it's one of your delimiters) to your code in proper sequence with the other tokens.  You'll have to add logic to figure out which tokens are delimiters and which are "real" tokens.